# Python Empty List of Tuples

Tags: python, list, while-loop, tuples, is-empty

A question from my assignment requires me to write a function that iterates through an input list of tuples using a while loop to then calculate how many days it took to reach a specific milestone. I have done part however I am also required to make my function return `None` if the input list is empty. The issue is I am only allowed to have one return statement in my code which is where I am stuck. How can I edit my code to add in this feature?

```
def days_to_reach_n_steps(step_records, n):
  """DOCSTRING"""
  total_steps = 0
  counter = 0
  while total_steps < n:
      total_steps = total_steps + step_records[counter][1]
      counter = counter + 1
  return(counter) here
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def days_to_reach_n_steps(step_records, n):
  """DOCSTRING"""
  total_steps = 0
  counter = 0
  if len(step_records)>0:
      while total_steps < n:
          if(counter <len(step_records):
              total_steps = total_steps + step_records[counter][1]
              counter = counter + 1
          else:
              counter = "Your Message"
  return(counter if counter!=0 else None)
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I have already tried this but got an error saying 'builtins.IndexError: list index out of range' . I think this error could be originating from my `total_steps = total_steps + step_records[counter][1]`. Maybe this line does not allow the input of empty lists? Any other ideas ?

Comment: why don't you use for loop, that error is because you are accessing an element in list, when the list is empty

Comment: Yeah using a for loop would be easier but this section of the assignment is on while loops so I am forced to exclude for loops unfortunately.

Comment: try to check the index in the list before accessing the list elements. That is by a if else loop.

Comment: I am assuming you mean something like `if len(step_records) >  0` (execute the while loop), however if the len(step_records) == 0 how would I tell the function to output `None` without using a second return sentence?

Comment: you will keep the return at the end, out of the if else loop

Comment: Could you please give an example of this? I don't really understand what needs to go under the if and else statements if I am keeping the return statement at the end.

Comment: Unless explicitly excluded, you could use a `while` loop by going `while true:// for loop //break

Comment: @KalyanReddy Thanks this works well, I have one final question though. How can I also make the function return a special message (`None` would do as well) if the total steps in the list never reaches n?

Comment: what do you mean, never reaches n, it is a while loop, it will ultimately reach n or else, just continuous to be in the loop

Comment: Yeah well I just noticed theres also a test case where n is given to be a large number that the sum of the steps in the list does not reach. So the test case is `step_records = [('2010-01-01',3),
                ('2010-01-02',2),
                ('2010-01-03',1)]
days = days_to_reach_n_steps(step_records, 50)
print(days)`  This outputs to an error.